# Getting just the application name from wmctrl -l

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal, wmctrl

I am trying to just get the application name out of this code:

```
wmctrl -l
```

but I don't know how to do it!

If you could please explain how I could do this, that would be great.

EDIT:

The output of `wmctrl -l` is:

```
0x01000007 -1 parrot Top Expanded Edge Panel
0x01000017 -1 parrot Bottom Expanded Edge Panel
0x01200006 -1 parrot x-caja-desktop
0x03600006  0 parrot Terminal
0x03000130  0 parrot scripting - Getting a string after a word in BASH - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange - Google Chrome
```

so I need everything after `parrot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several ways to do it. Depending on your preferred type of tool, you might choose one over other

#### AWK

Most appropriate way. Set words 1,2,3 to empty string and print

```
$ wmctrl -l | awk '{$1=$2=$3="";print}'
```

Alternatively to get rid of leading space, you can do this:

```
$ wmctrl -l | awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}'
```

#### cut

A little awkward approach, we print everything after specific field till field 9999. Why 9999 ? `-f` flag apparently needs to know range, so with input that have arbitrary number of words per line, we obviously can't know the range, but we can use something sufficiently large, hence 9999.

```
$ wmctrl -l | cut -d " " -f 5-9999
```

#### Perl

We can take advantage of `-a` autosplit mode, where words of each line read from stdin are split into array. This potentially could be improved and shortened.

```
$ wmctrl  -l | perl -lane 'my $numels=scalar @F;print @F[3..$numels]'
```

#### Python

Slightly lengthy but works. Python doesn't have auto split mode like perl , but we can do so manually on each string read.

```
$ wmctrl -l | python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join([' '.join(line.split()[3:]) for line in sys.stdin])"
```

Alternatively we can use a short script for to simulate `cut`, instead of one-liner. This would work much better for multiline texts/inputs and is much more readable

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

start=int(sys.argv[1])
for line in sys.stdin:
    print " ".join(line.strip().split()[start:])
```

And call it as so:

```
$ wmctrl -l | ./print_words.py 3
```

#### SED

This way takes advantage of regular expressions. We match string from the beginning of line `^` till word boundary `parrot` with `\b` and following space, and delete them (effectively setting to null string)

```
$ wmctrl -l | sed 's/^.*\bparrot\ //'
```

Alternatively to avoid greedy matching, we can use the following:

```
$ wmctrl -l | sed 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* //'
```

The pattern isn't too complex.We start matching at beginning of the line, and matching any number of characters (the `*` part) that are not space (`[^ ]` part) three times separated by any number of spaces. So  `^[^ ]*` matches first word, `*` matches any number of spaces, second `[^ ]*` matches second word, and second `*` matches second space, finally with `[^ ]*` matching 3rd word plus space.

#### BASH + xargs

We can take advantage of bash's ability to iterate over command-line arguments, and pass each line ( -L 1 ) as set of command-line arguments to `bash -c ' '`. The rest is simple - we get rids of first 3 arguments, and print the rest

```
wmctrl -l | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'for i in 1 2 3;do shift ; done ; printf "%s " "$@";printf "\n"' sh
```

Alternatively, as suggested by Stephane Chazelas in the comments: as long as there are at least 3 positional arguments being passed from `wmctrl -l` (which in this case should be consistently true), the solution can be shortened to :

```
wmctrl -l | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'shift 3;printf "%s " "$@";printf "\n"' sh
```

Comment: `cut -f5-` to cut from 5th field to the end. Anyway it won't work here as the number of spaces between the fields is not the same on every line.

Comment: `for i in 1 2 3; do shift; done` can be shorten to `shift 3` as long as the number of positional parameters is at least 3.

Comment: `print` in your second example prints the whole record (same as `print $0`). Use `print ""` or `printf "\n"` to print a newline character.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, corrected. Was written in haste.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) as [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) (correctly) lacks filtering options.
Likely this is what you want:

```
wmctrl -l | cut -d ' ' -f 4-
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of space characters in-between the fields is not the same on every line, so `cut` can't be used like that.

Comment: If you don't mind loosing duplicate spaces in the last column, you could use `tr -s ' '` between `wcmtrl` and `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/.* parrot //p'
```

Would print what's on the right of the *rightmost* occurrence of `" parrot "` on the lines that contain `" parrot "`. That's because that `.*` above is greedy and will match as much as possible.

In your case, that would be a problem for output like:

```
0x03a00003  0 parrot parrot (~) (1 of 2) - GVIM
```

If you want to print what's on the right of the *leftmost* occurrence of `" parrot "`, a common trick is to do:

```
sed -n '/ parrot /{
  s//\
/; s/.*/\n/p
}'
```

That is, we replace the first (so leftmost) occurrence of `" parrot "` with newline (a character that otherwise will never be found in the pattern space). And then remove everything up to that newline (which is guaranteed to be unique).

Here though, it looks like you want the title of the windows from the `parrot` client, so the from lines where the third field is `parrot`, so:

```
sed -n 's/^[^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}[^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}parrot //p'
```

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if s/^\H+\h+\H+\h+parrot //'
```

Note that we're assuming that the window titles don't contain newline characters which is usually the case but not guaranteed. Try for instance after:

```
xterm -n $'foo\nbar'
```

If you wanted to account for that, you could do instead:

```
perl -0777 -ne '$prefix = qr{0x[\da-f]+\h+-?\d+\h+};
                print for /^${prefix}parrot (.*?\n)(?=$prefix|$)/gms'
```

That is use the fact that all entries start with `0x<hex> <dec>` to identify where records start and end. That would not be completely foolproof (like for the case of someone doing `xterm -n $'foo\n0x0 0 parrot something'`), but should be OK when not faced with malicious users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
wmctrl -l | sed 's/|/ /' | awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}'
```

which will not count the "-" in "-1" for sticky windows as a column.

Comment: This is great, but most of the applications have names with more that just one word, so `awk '{print $4}'` would print `Top` instead of `Top Expanded Edge Panel
`

Comment: Good point, that is a limitation.  I'm not enough of a sed expert to know a work around right off, but that just may not be the way to go.

Comment: @MaliciouZzHD, I changed the command in my answer so it prints the whole application name, including spaces.  I tried it out a few times and it seems to work fine, though it leaves a few spaces at the beginning of the line.  Will this work?  I think I know a (hackish) way around it if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim fixed width output with
`wmctrl -l | cut -c15-`

Comment: You're right, but your `15` only works for a machine name `parrot` or another one also of 6 characters. Can you generalise your solution at all?

Comment: That's the nature of fixed width records :-) There are enought answers columns with variable length.